# How to save the state of popup.html in the current tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs, popup, firefox-addon

I have a checkbox on the popup of the extension and I want to save the status of the checkbox for every page.

I've tried using `browser.storage.local` but it will be shared within different tabs that have the extension running.

How do you save the sate of a checkbox in popup.html that is unique for every opened tabs?

Comment: Use the tab id or URL as the key ([related](/a/17826527)).

Comment: i was thinking of using that one but is there any options?

Comment: There's no such thing as a per-tab extension storage.

Answer (score 0):

Every open tab, will be opened to a different page, so you can use window.location of each open tab, and then you can use [Chrome.Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) to save a [key pair Object](https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries), of the Checkbox State, and window.location.

Have your popup.js include the chrome.storage.get to retrieve the variable from local storage at the top of the script.  Include popup.js in your popup.html.

You would need to have some type of IF/ELSE statement to say, if window.location is equal to what's in the Chrome.storage.get, then checkbox state is...